# Using WHERE clause on a joined table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to find the best way to filter out rows by using conditions based on a joined table.  As an example I am joining the employees and salary grade table based on the salary grade for each employee. Then I want to show only the employees that have the same grade as a certain employee (Blake). I used the following code:

```
SELECT e.ename, e.sal, sg.grade  
FROM emp e JOIN salgrade sg  
ON(e.sal BETWEEN sg.losal AND sg.hisal)  
WHERE sg.grade = (SELECT sg.grade FROM emp e JOIN salgrade sg ON(e.sal BETWEEN sg.losal AND sg.hisal) WHERE e.ename = 'BLAKE')  
ORDER BY e.sal DESC
```

Is there a more optimal way to write the query?

Comment: What database system are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Comment: I'm using Oracle*

Comment: Can we see some sample data from both tables please?

Comment: That sub-query seems a bit dangerous...

Comment: Surely emp has a column that maps to the salary grade.
Looks open to cartesean products

Comment: Well I just ended up copying the main query as my subquery, since I have to idea of how else I can get the salary grade for a certain employee.

Comment: This query does end up giving me the desired output though. It just feels very.... arbitrary? Feeling like I'm missing something that can make the entire statement a lot shorter.

Comment: The emp tables contains employee_nr, ename and salary, the salary grade table contains a grade, lowest and highest salary. That's why I joined it based on the salary in emp being between the highest and lowest salary in the grades table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method that uses window functions:

```
SELECT es.*
FROM (SELECT e.ename, e.sal, sg.grade,
             MAX(CASE WHEN e.ename = 'BLAKE' THEN sg.grade END) OVER () as blake_grade
      FROM emp e JOIN
           salgrade sg  
           ON e.sal BETWEEN sg.losal AND sg.hisal 
     ) es
WHERE grade = blake_grade 
ORDER BY e.sal DESC;
```

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I am trying to do, but this is beyond the scope of my current course. Maybe the way I did it might be the only way to go about it with the stuff I was thought.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a join in the select in the WHERE clause; rather, I would use an inner scalar subquery to pick up BLAKE's salary and then an outer scalar subquery to pick up his salgrade. Otherwise very similar to your query:

```
select e.ename, e.sal, s.grade
from   emp e inner join salgrade s on e.sal between s.losal and s.hisal
where  s.grade = ( select grade 
                   from   salgrade 
                   where  (select sal from emp where ename = 'BLAKE') 
                                                        between losal and hisal
                 )
order by sal desc
;
```

Using the same idea, you could do away with the first join as well (by returning the `losal` and `hisal` for BLAKE as well as his `salgrade`), but perhaps that is taking it too far.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, much less arbitrary. The thing I didn't like about my code was that I was using the join in the subquery and for some reason I couldn't think of any other way to find it than using the joined table. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If this is just about not having to write the same code twice, you can use a `WITH` clause:

```
WITH emps_and_sals AS
(
  SELECT e.ename, e.sal, sg.grade  
  FROM emp e 
  JOIN salgrade sg ON e.sal BETWEEN sg.losal AND sg.hisal
)
SELECT *
FROM emps_and_sals
WHERE grade = (SELECT grade FROM emps_and_sals WHERE ename = 'BLAKE')  
ORDER BY sal DESC;
```